# Passing YUV data from Tango to C++ plugin causes bad memory access

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

My app is in Unity and uses Google Tango SDK. I'm getting YUV image buffer delivered to `OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler`, from there, I need to retrieve individual Y, U and V buffers and pass them to C++ plugin. Here's what I do:

```
public class LibraryWrapper {
    [DllImport ("library")]
    public static extern void incomingI420Frame(uint width, uint height, 
      uint strideY, uint strideU, uint strideV,
      IntPtr yPlane, IntPtr uPlane, IntPtr vPlane);
}

public void OnTangoImageAvailableEventHandler(Tango.TangoEnums.TangoCameraId cameraId, Tango.TangoUnityImageData imageBuffer)
{
    uint offset = imageData.stride; // offset, because first scanline is a metadata, according to Tango documentation 
    uint yPlaneSize = imageData.width * imageData.height;
    uint vPlaneSize = imageData.width / 2 * imageData.height / 2;
    uint uPlaneSize = vPlaneSize;

    GCHandle pinnedBuffer = GCHandle.Alloc (imageData.data, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    IntPtr yPlane = new IntPtr (pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject ().ToInt64 () + offset);
    offset += yPlaneSize;
    IntPtr vPlane = new IntPtr (pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject ().ToInt64 () + offset);
    offset += vPlaneSize;
    IntPtr uPlane = new IntPtr (pinnedBuffer.AddrOfPinnedObject ().ToInt64 () + offset);

    Debug.Log ("processing frame... " + imageData.width + "x" + imageData.height + " total size " + imageData.data.Length);
    Debug.Log ("stride " + imageData.stride + ". yplane " + String.Format("{0:X}", yPlane) + " (" + yPlaneSize + " bytes)");
    Debug.Log ("uplane " + String.Format("{0:X}", uPlane) + " (" + uPlaneSize + " bytes)");
    Debug.Log ("vplane " + String.Format("{0:X}", vPlane) + " (" + vPlaneSize + " bytes)");

    LibraryWrapper.incomingI420Frame (imageData.width, imageData.height,
        yPlaneSize, uPlaneSize, vPlaneSize, yPlane, uPlane, vPlane);

    pinnedBuffer.Free ();
}
```

C++ library function is:

```
void incomingI420Frame(
        const unsigned int width,
        const unsigned int height,
        const unsigned int strideY,
        const unsigned int strideU,
        const unsigned int strideV,
        const unsigned char* yBuffer,
        const unsigned char* uBuffer,
        const unsigned char* vBuffer);
```

Application crashes on `memcpy` of the data:

```
08-09 14:42:42.789  9384  9401 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 9401 (UnityMain)
 backtrace:
08-09 14:42:42.907   542   542 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00016978  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+104)
```

Obviously, I messed up with pointer, however I don't see how - I'm using `GCHandle` to pin the buffer, so it shouldn't move, right? Moreover call to C++ happens in the same thread, so I doubt GC will ever have a chance to touch the buffer. Thus, I suspect, error might be in calculating pointers for Y, U or V data.

Comment: If it crashes on `memcpy` you have to also post that part that uses `memcpy` and where you are copying and writing to.

Comment: I'm not sure about first scanline being metadata, as [docs don't mention it](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/tango-unity-image-data#class_tango_1_1_tango_unity_image_data_1a0cec79b5bfb41f2f44e1533b5ff04237). Plane size calculations should be based on strides e.g. `yPlaneSize = imageData.stride * imageData.height;` Also you are passing plane sizes as strides into `incomingI420Frame`.

Comment: thanks! i'll double check that. here's the [link](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/interface/i-tango-video-overlay) where it mentions metadata.